# If statement not working in this for loop

Tags: r, if-statement

```
Percent <- data.frame(matrix(, nrow = 207842, ncol = 90))
for ( j in 1 : nrow(justvalues))
{ 
  m=3
  n=2
  o=1
  for( i in 4 : ncol(justvalues))
  {
   k <- subset(justvalues, Year.of.Date == justvalues[j,i-m]-1 & Quarter.of.Date == justvalues[j,i-n] & Values.A == justvalues[j,i-o])  
   p <- k[i]
   g <- as.numeric(p)
   ifelse(g==0, Percent[j,i] = "NA" , Percent[j,i] = ((justvalues[j,i]-g)/g)*100)
   m=m+1
   n=n+1
   o=o+1
  }
}
```

Error: unexpected '=' in "ifelse(g == 0, Percent[j,i] ="

This is the error I am getting. Please check.

Comment: Is this your complete program?  And, you should probably edit your question to include the language, and add a tag for that language, as I don't know what language this is.

Comment: You can't do that in `ifelse()`.Factor the assignment out.  That line should be `Percent[j,i] <- ifelse(g==0, NA , ((justvalues[j,i]-g)/g)*100)`. But there is probably a better way.  What is it you are attempting to accomplish?

Comment: remove the quotes around NA.. I think

Comment: @RichardScriven It worked like a pro!! Bunch of Thanks!

Comment: many things in R can be vectorized, it is often unnessecary to loop over rows and columns and can make things very slow.

Comment: @Heroka Is there any method rather than looping through rows and columns?..to go through each cell and manipulate it?

Comment: @SaiKrishna depends on what you're doing, but many, many things are/can be vectorized.